# Upgraded from SQL Server 2014 to 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I upgraded my SQL Server from 2014 to 2017 however when I try to use this function STRING_AGG it seems like it's nowhere to be found. Did I miss something during the upgrade?

Comment: did you update compatibility level for your database?

Comment: Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: And what exactly does "nowhere to be found" mean? Did you attempt to use it and your code generated an error? What does the query `select @@version` return?

Comment: I got this when running @@version Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
 Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Update your compatibility level as @DanielN states. In SSMS right-click on the database, click "Properties" => click "Options" and then set your compatibility level to SQL Server 2017 (140).

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find the script in order to change the compatibility level

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET compatibility_level = 140
GO
```